# Select Item from Listview using iteminvoke in Javascript

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have a ListView with items. I am trying get clicked item from Listview using "iteminvoked".

```
    <div id="listView_Id" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
     data-win-options="{
            itemTemplate: select('#smallListIconTextTemplate'),
            selectionMode: 'single',
            tapBehavior: 'none',
            layout: { type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout }
        }">
   </div>
```

Here ListArray is array of values with filenames picked using 'FilePicker'

```
        dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List(listArray);
        var listControlDiv = document.getElementById("listView_Id");
        var listControl = listControlDiv.winControl;
        listControl.itemDataSource = dataList.dataSource;
```

I set ListView dataSource from JS file rather than HTML file by fallowing this [question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6f85d8e6-de9f-4a9f-b6e2-16aee8e3375e/define-picked-files-from-file-picker-as-listview-datasource?forum=winappswithhtml5#48eacad2-3aaa-4afd-9208-7813eb5db11b).

I created handler like this.

```
document.getElementById("listView_Id").addEventListener("iteminvoked", doClickItem, false);
```

But unfortunately, My `doClickItem` handler doesn't call at any way. While in same manner select item from Listview which is working Fine.

I guess I set Listview datasource using Javascript(The items source will be Change repeatedly). What is the wrong I did here.

[Here](http://sdrv.ms/1c2aEbC) is my complete project to try
Thanks

Comment: I did using this [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/27d071a9-e23c-481b-9083-f87d008ba075/select-item-from-listview-using-iteminvoke-in-javascript?forum=winappswithhtml5 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
 var listControl = document.getElementById("listView_Id").winControl;
 listControl.addEventListener("iteminvoked", doClickItem, false);
```

Comment: I done it. The mistake done by me is setting the tapbehavior to none; `tapBehavior: 'none'`. After change to `invokeOnly`. it is working fine. I already mention in comment under my question, Anyway Thanks for your time